# Right Justify Paragragh

Tags: paragraphs

I can get the paragraph on the right side of the page with `\raggedleft` on `flushright` enviroment, but how to make it justified? I mean something like:

```
                                                            text text text, text
                                                            text a. text b  text
                                                            foo bar foo bar  foo
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Probably you want to use a `minipage` environment or a `\parbox{}` on the right? However, justifying text is not really recommended for such a narrow width and will pretty much inevitably look bad.

Comment: how would it be like? I have no choice, have to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\hspace*{\fill}\begin{minipage}{30mm}
Whatever text you like.
\end{minipage}

\hspace*{\fill}\parbox{30mm}{Whatever text you like.}
```

Untested as you've not provided an MWE.